# How unit test WCF Services / Service Host initializes DI, AutoMapper, bootstrapping, global error handling properly?

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, integration-testing, servicehost

I have several things that I haven't figured out how to test because they are tightly integrated to the WCF pipeline. Maybe I should ask how to integration test? Here's my situation, two parts:

1) To bootstrap my DI (I'm using Unity Container), I have implemented a custom ServiceHostFactory. In this service host factory, I pass in my bootstrapper code (e.g. for AutoMapper and other things).

How do I test all these items get *called* and that my configurations are correct? Granted, as I type this, maybe this should be considered integration testing? How do I host my service and test it with my tests?

2) I also have a global error handler for my services. I'd like to write a mock test to throw an exception and verify that the global error handler is in fact catching them.

Thanks!

Update:
Maybe my question isn't very clear, but after some more googling, I think [this](http://www.typemock.com/blog/2009/06/11/wcf-tip-how-to-unit-test-an-errorprovider) is what I'm after

Additional thoughts or pointers appreciated. Haven't tried it yet as I'm not sure which direction I should be going.